# Can I trust the file type from $_FILES?

Tags: php, security, upload

Can I trust the file type from `$_FILES` when uploading images? Or do I have to check again with `exif_imagetype()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot trust the `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` variable. The value present in this variable could be forged. You can use [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to detect file type more reliably:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // we need mime type
echo finfo_file($finfo, "/path/to/uploaded/file"); // displays something like image/gif
finfo_close($finfo);
```

These functions require PHP >= 5.3.0.

Answer (score 4):

Never trust anything that comes from the outside, **especially** file uploads!

Check the size, location, mime/type, extenstion and anything else you can check!

Comment: But does the type come from the outside? Or is it something added by php?

Comment: The browser provides it, do not trust it.

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp agreed, also check the *contents* if you can.

Answer (score 3):

I always use the next function to check on valid images :

```
function Check_Image($Filename) {
    if ($Check_Image = @getimagesize($Filename)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**No, you cannot trust it because [this information is provided by the client browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).**

> `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` The mime type of the file, if the browser
>   provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime
>   type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take
>   its value for granted.